Pyimage not detecting image in line 2
I am trying to create a python script that can run the same imageJ macro on all images in a directory. I am currently using the pyimagej library but I have been having some issues with the script particularly understanding how to access the image in question in headless mode. In order to troubleshoot the code I attempted to create a smaller less complicated script where I open an image and perform a gaussian blur see below.
import imagej
import os

# Initialize ImageJ
ij = imagej.init()

# Load the image
image_path = "C:/Users/antho/OneDrive/Documents/NerettiLab/SenID/Data/Cycling_cells/Cycling_img_raw/MAX_20221011_cyclingsampleDapi_CellEvent_C20221111_stitched.nd2 - ...cyclingsampleDapi_CellEvent_C20221111_stitched(series 23).tif"
image = ij.io().open(image_path)

# Define the macro as a string
macro_code = """
run("Gaussian Blur...", "sigma=2");
"""

cells = ij.WindowManager.getCurrentImage()

# Run the macro
ij.py.run_macro(macro_code)

# Save the processed image
output_path = "C:/Users/antho/OneDrive/Documents/NerettiLab/SenID/Data/Cycling_cells/Processed_C20221111_stitched(series 23).tif"
ij.io().save(image, output_path)

# Close ImageJ
ij.dispose()

image = ij.io().open('sample-data/test_image.tif')
args = {"image":image}

However, I seem to be getting the following error:

(MorphologyDL) PS
C:\Users\antho\OneDrive\Documents\NerettiLab\imagejcode> python
.\shortmarco.py Operating in headless mode - the original ImageJ will
have limited functionality. Operating in headless mode - the
WindowManager class will not be fully functional. Macro Error: There
are no images open in line 2
run ( "Gaussian Blur..." , "sigma=2" <)> ; Traceback (most recent call
last):   File "DefaultIOService.java", line 97, in
org.scijava.io.DefaultIOService.save io.scif.img.ImgIOException:
io.scif.img.ImgIOException: io.scif.FormatException: SCIFIO exception
when writing to file
FileLocation:file:/C:/Users/antho/OneDrive/Documents/NerettiLab/SenID/Data/Cycling_cells/Processed_C20221111_stitched(series%2023).tif:
Attempting to write to output that already exists. Please rename the
output, remove the existing conflict, or adjust configuration.
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "DefaultIOService.java",
line 97, in org.scijava.io.DefaultIOService.save Exception: Java
Exception
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\antho\OneDrive\Documents\NerettiLab\imagejcode\shortmarco.py",
line 23, in 
ij.io().save(image, output_path) java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: io.scif.img.ImgIOException:
io.scif.FormatException: SCIFIO exception when writing to file
FileLocation:file:/C:/Users/antho/OneDrive/Documents/NerettiLab/SenID/Data/Cycling_cells/Processed_C20221111_stitched(series%2023).tif:
Attempting to write to output that already exists. Please rename the
output, remove the existing conflict, or adjust configuration.

The pyimagej documentation just has this example code but it doesn't show any input image.
ij.py.run_macro("""run("Blobs (25K)");""")
blobs = ij.WindowManager.getCurrentImage()
print(blobs)

I assume that the macro would run on the current image but this is also somewhat confusing as the error seems to show that their is no image to run its gaussian blur on. ie.

Macro Error: There are no images open in line 2

I was wondering if there was something I am doing wrong?
Here is an example of the python code I am actually trying to implement which utilizes a for loop to apply the same macro for each image in the folder. The macrocode would be slightly different where it would essentially apply fiji's 3D registration algorithm to correct for 3D drift in the image over time.
import imagej
import os
import pathlib

# Initialize ImageJ
ij = imagej.init('sc.fiji:fiji')  # Initializes the Fiji version of ImageJ, adjust as necessary

# Define the directory with your images
image_directory = "C:/Users/antho/OneDrive/Documents/NerettiLab/SenID/Data/Cycling_cells/Cycling_img_raw"
macro_path = "C:/Users/antho/OneDrive/Documents/NerettiLab/SenID/Data/Cycling_cells/SplitandThreshold.ijm.ijm.ijm"  # Path to the ImageJ macro file
available_languages = ij.script().getLanguages()
for language in available_languages:
    print(language.getLanguageName())
macro_code ="""
  // Example macro: Split Channels
  if (nImages > 0) {
      run("Split Channels");
  } else {
      print("No images open");
  }
"""
# Get the list of all files in the directory
image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(image_directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(image_directory, f))]

# Loop through each file and apply the macro
for image_file in image_files:
    image_path = os.path.join(image_directory, image_file)

    try:
        # Open the image in ImageJ
        image = ij.io().open(image_path)
        if image is not None:
            # Show the image in the ImageJ UI
            ij.ui().show(image)

            # Run the macro file on the currently opened image
            result = ij.py.run_macro(macro_code)
        else:
            print(f"Failed to open image: {image_file}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {image_file}: {e}")


# Close ImageJ when done
ij.context().dispose()


To better understand your issue, it would help if you could tell us whether you are trying to improve your Python-coding skills or if you are trying to get a processing job done. If the latter is most important than I'd use the ImageJ macro language.

Hey Herbie thank you for your reply! I want to say I am trying to get the processing job done but I would be helpful if it was done in python to help implement the code as part of an already partially constructed pipeline. I edited the end of the post to show what I actually want the code to do where it loops through each image in a folder and applies the macro code. The macro code is slightly different from what the end result would be as the final purpose of the code would be to apply imageJ's 3D registration algorithm. Hope this helps and thank you again.

Agreed, although my experience tells me that it is better to stick to the original languages, here: Java and the intimately associated macro language. Good luck!
